# Discrepancy in "Towers of Midnight"

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In WoT 13, Towers of Midnight, Tam is with Perrin and Rand at the same time. He goes to Rand, talks with him. At the same time, it is told him speaking with Perrin and crew. No mention of him being taken from Perrin's side by Aes Sedai. Because then Perrin would know all about what was happening in Tear from the Aes Sedai. No mention of Tam coming back either. It says Rand sent Tam back to Two Rivers.

**How was Tam in both places at the same time?**

Comment: There is a mention of tam being taken, right before or after the battle to free faile. you have to understand that perrin's story is out of sync time wise to the rest of the books. perrins story is some times as much as a couple months behind the main story line, it finally catches up once they meet with Galad, and arrive in camelyn. And tam does not come back, he does return to the two rivers and arrives back to perrin before the final battles with a final group of two rivers men, as well as a large supply of arrows that rand had tam prepare.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: This was a common question/discussion on fan sites when the book came out. I'm surprised it hasn't been asked here yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, Tam's not really with both of them at the same time. That novel just does a terrible job of explaining where the various characters are in relation to each other's time lines.

This isn't the first time, either; *Crossroads of Twilight* was almost entirely scenes that ran in parallel to the end of *Winter's Heart*.

In *Towers of Midnight*, you need to pay attention to the times that Perrin "sees" Rand, either through his visions or, near the end, in person. That will give you a clue how far back you need to go to find that same spot in Rand's point of view. In particular, in *The Gathering Storm*, Cadsuane brings Tam to Rand in an attempt to stop him from going full-evil; however, when we first see Perrin in *Towers of Midnight*, **this hasn't happened yet**. It's not until much later in Perrin's story that we reach the point where Rand is atop Dragonmount going nuclear, which happened right after Rand's fight with Tam.

Comment: its not actually that bad in explaining time relations, because almost every scene with perrin or with mat gives a vision of the others to compare where they are at in the story, Perrins story particularly is almost always behind though, more so then the others. but this is something you see most fantasy writters doing, we see it extensively in the game of thrones series, and in the malazan series. ( the 2 most comparable series in length and scope)

Comment: no, once you know what to look for it's fine, but I'm pretty sure I didn't make the connection until very late in Perrin's story line that we had jumped back several days. At least in CoT it was obvious from the fact that everyone was staring at the Cleansing.

Comment: Now I know, I was still reading while I asked. Now I read in Chapter 29, when Tam comes to Perrin and asks leave to go to Rand. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it _is_ very bad at explaining. Nothing like this has happened in the other 13+1 books, _and_ this book has been known to be rushed, so…

Comment: Good thing the internal search works well when you start typing your question, so I found this answer before I posted the same question. Also thanks from my side for the answer. And I am used to parallel or a bit of time discrepancy between characters but here it could have been done differently, by placing the Perrin chapters earlier...

Answer (score 1):

@kutuluMike did a great job explaining what happened, so I thought I would share why it happened.

Brandon Sanderson originally wrote the final novel as one gigantic book.  After pushback from the Publisher that it wasn't feasible, nor good business sense to release such a large book with so many pages, they broke the book into three volumes.

Because of this, story lines had to be shuffled around a bit for them to make sense and allow for a satisfying climax to each novel.

He actually specifically commented on that on his blog in a retrospective blog post titled "THE WHEEL OF TIME RETROSPECTIVE: TOWERS OF MIDNIGHT: WHAT I LEARNED" in which he said:

> When we split the books, some of the timeline things I’d done got too far out of sync. At the end of Knife of Dreams, the character viewpoints were somewhat out of sync, as Robert Jordan often wrote them. I didn’t have any experience juggling something like this, and in Towers of Midnight I flubbed it. Not that the timeline is messed up—it’s actually pretty good, all things considered.

> However, the perception of it brought us troubles. Because characters interacted across timelines, it felt like they were in two places at once (Tam is an example) even though it all worked narratively.
> This made for some confusing moments for readers. Mr. Jordan did things like this without distracting; I didn’t juggle this as well, and because of it, I think the book suffered

Why did they split it?  He also talked about that too, on this blog post [Splitting a Memory of Light](https://www.brandonsanderson.com/splitting-a-memory-of-light/)

> By this point, I’d already warned Tom and Harriet that I saw the length being very large, but I hadn’t told Tom **the 700–800k number[of words]**. When I’d mentioned 400k to him once, he’d been wary. **He explained to me that he felt 400k was unprintably large in today’s publishing market.** Things have changed since the 90’s, and booksellers are increasingly frustrated with the fantasy genre, which tends to take up a lot of shelf space with very few books. There is constant pressure from the big chain bookstores to keep things smaller and thinner. When I’d turned in Mistborn 2 (revised and already trimmed) at 250k, production and marketing had nearly had a fit, complaining that the book would cost more to print than it would make. Tom approved the publication of the book anyway. (And fortunately we managed to fit it into enough pages—and sell enough copies—that it was still profitable.)

**TLDR** book stores don't like fantasy books being gigantic and taking tons of shelf room.  This might matter less today in this ebook first world but it was still a big deal in 2009.

https://www.brandonsanderson.com/the-wheel-of-time-retrospective-towers-of-midnight-what-i-learned/